# Magento Multi Store with multiple domains

Tags: magento2

I'm having a major issue here getting the multi store function to work with Magento 2. Currently everything *seems* set up right but the 2nd domain is redirecting straight to the main store view instead of the one set up for it.

I've been on with our hosts tech support and they can't see the issue either.

So the original website santa.com has 
Web Site has:

name: main website 
store code: base
Default store: Santa

Store has:
Default store view: Santa

Store view has:
Store: Main Website Store
Name: Santa
Code: default

The 2nd site has

Website:
Name: Rudolph
code: rudolph
Default Store: Rudolph

Store has:
Name: Rudolph
Default Store View: Rudolph

Store view:
Store: Rudolph
Name: Rudolph
Code: Rudolph

Under Stores configuration for the Rudolph

Base URL: http://rudolph.com/
Base Link URL is default {{unsecure_base_url}}
Static view and Media are both blank and use default checked

Secure base URL https://rudolph.com/
Base Link URL is default {{secure_base_url}}
Static view and Media are both blank and use default checked

Default Pages
Default Web URL cms (use default is checked)
CMS Homepage is the Rudolph page I created

Then I 301'ed rudolph.com to Santa.com

Once I did that I moved on to the index.php and .htaccess. I've tried several different configurations here but none give the right result. Currently the .htaccess has these changes:

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
SetEnvIf Host .*fountains.ie.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=waterfeatures
SetEnvIf Host .*fountains.ie.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

#RewriteBase /magento/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:rudolph.santa.com]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com
RewriteRule .* – [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

And the index.php is

```
try {
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
    <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
    Autoload error</h3>
</div>
<p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
exit(1);
}

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'rudolph';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

This is on Plesk at the moment and most frustratingly Ive got this to work on a test installation through cPanel with a different host.

I'm possibly missing something stupid obvious here, but any and all help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!